# TFSMigrator error: non interactive login is not yet supported in this tool

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, migration

When I run TFSMigrator (16.132.28529.3) using the /tenantDomainName parameter, it get the following error:

```
[Error  @15:55:31.963] Non interactive login is not yet supported in this tool
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error when running the tool from PowerShell ISE. 
I switched to an old CMD console and the AzureAD login page is popping up.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should not run the migrator tool with /NoPrompt option.

other recommendations:
use the same account to sign in to your windows machine.
open the browser and try to sign in to the dev.azure.com before running the migrator tool.
open the command window in administrator mode